# How to invoke a PL/SQL procedure stored on an Oracle database from R

Tags: r, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am running the following version of R under Windows 7.

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Using library(RODBC),

```
channel <- odbcConnect(dsn = "database")

ProcExec <- "execute LENGTHCOMP(2004)"  
# the procedure returns nothing, but creates a series of Oracle tables needed later in the R function
sqlQuery(channel = channel, query = ProcExec, believeNRows = FALSE)

odbcClose(channel)
```

returns error:

```
[1] "42000 0 [Oracle][ODBC]Syntax error or access violation."               
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'execute LENGTHCOMP(2004)'"   .
```

Library ROracle (August 2013) indicates

dbCallProc-methods 
  Call an SQL stored procedure
Description
  Not yet implemented.

Are their other R packages that provide functionality to invoke a stored PL/SQL procedure on Oracle? or is there a way to make sqlQuery do it from the RODBC package?

Comment: I have the very same question.  Has anyone found an answer or a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Using ROracle, I have succeeded by creating a PLSQL-function to wrap the procedure call:

```
create or replace function Wrapper_func (Sql_in in varchar2)
  return number
  authid current_user
as
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  execute immediate Sql_in;
  return 0;
exception
  when others then
    return sqlcode;
end Wrapper_func;
```

This I call from R:

```
sqldata<-dbGetQuery(con, "select wrapper_func ('begin proc_t(137); end;') from dual")
```

The function returns 0 if the procedurecall succeeds, and the errorcode, if the procedurecall fails. The procedure needs to run as current_user, since it will execute any sql given to it.

The proper way is probably to wrap all procedurecall with specific functioncalls that matches the signature of the procedurecall. These functions need not be current_user, since they only pass parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above method to call procedure from R but you can't run procedures involving DML and DDL operations from functions.

I found another way to execute procedure as sql statement without using wrapper function.

**stmt <- paste("Begin proc(:1,:2,:3);End;")**

**dbSendQuery(con,stmt,df) or oracleProc(con,stmt,df)**

I have used ROracle library here.

df is the dataframe containing parameters you want to pass in procedure proc.

Hope it helps !!